# Co-recurisive workflows not starting on second cycle

Tags: sharepoint-2007, workflow

**My scenario is:***

Workflow A - configured to start when a new item is created in List A:
Creates a new list item in List B.

Workflow B - configured to start when a new item is created in List B:
Creates a new list item in List A.

**When I test this i get the following:** 
I manually create a list item in List A. 
Workflow A fires and creates a new list item in List B. 
Workflow B fires and creates a new list item in List A.
**But**  a new instance of Workflow A **does not** instantiate on the created in List by Workflow B.

### ---**edit**-----
Is this happening because the item created in List A by Workflow B is created by System Account thus not firing Workflow A?

---------**edit**---------------------------------------

I am aware this is causes an infinite loop there is a pause for duration action set to 1 year in workflow A. So it fires in yearly cycles.

I know sp2 prevents infinite loops being created on the same list but from what i read of the article below suggests this is possible to do cross lists as in my scenario.
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sharepointdesigner/service-pack-2-prevents-an-on-change-workflow-from-starting-itself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was co-recursive workflows do **not** work cross lists as I assummed. The msdn blog link above scenario uses two workflows on the **same** list. I adjusted my workflows to use the same list.

The error was output to my log files but since logging was not set to verbose i didn't see it.